# how do I tighten retaining ring on lamp sconce

Tags: lamp

Need help with fixture.
How do I tighten retaining ring on lamp sconce with out retaining ring wrench?
Thanks

Comment: I usually use a long flat blade screwdriver and tighten it by hitting the nut on an edge with a screwdriver with another tool some times a hammer, sometimes a pair of players, many times pliers are tough to get in there but a flat blade screwdriver with a smack on the edge I tighten everything from 3/8 to 6" conduit.

Comment: Is this in British or something? Finger tight; that's why it's knurled. Or are we talking about lock nuts on an EMT-to-box connector? That's when you bang on it with a screw driver.

Answer (score 0):

Channel Locks or Crescent wrench if you can fit it in there. If not buy a wrench replacement. I see them going for $4 at Sears and Walmart.

http://www.sears.com/westinghouse-70000-4.75inch-shade-ring-wrench-70000/p-SPM11121753313

https://www.walmart.com/ip/Westinghouse-70000-4-75-Shade-Ring-Wrench-70000-4-3-4-SHADE-RING-WRENCH/160937339

[image]

Comment: Or properly adjusted vice-grips.

Comment: I have never seen or used a wrench like that for a fixture. Electricians use channel lock type pliers and or a driver like a chizzle or screwdriver to tighten nuts.

Comment: Use pliers on the fitting, not the nut. Start it so it will end up facing the right way if it's a screw-type connector... assuming there's no drywall yet.